# Returning python object in httpresponse

Tags: python, django

I have a python function in the view which returns an object, now i want to call this function from another function which actually returns HTTPResponse. How can i return both the python object and AJAX response together?
First method returning python object.

```
def Populate_Config_Resources():
    data = ResourceManager.objects.filter(verified = 1)
    return data
```

second method returning httpresponse.

```
def Update_ResourceManager(request):
    try:
        do something...

    except Exception,e:
        return HttpResponse(e)

    # here I call that function.
    config_data = Populate_Config_Resources()
    return HttpResponse('success')
```

Comment: This question is a bit confusing. You don't seem to be using a template anywhere - you need to pass your object to the template render function.

Comment: Roseman, i definitely use a template but i didn't include it in my post as my problem was to send the object which i was not able to do, once i have sent it successfully i will iterate over it in the template. nonetheless, thank you, i will post the code from my template next time i ask such question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an AJAX response for that return value, then use:

```
return HttpResponse(json.dumps(config_data), content_type="application/json")
```

Or if you are using a template:

```
template = loader.get_template('config.html')
context = RequestContext(request, {"config_data": config_data})
return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

Comment: Instead of `content_type` this should be `mimetype`. Otherwise you will get `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'content_type' azure function`

Answer (score 0):

use   the code given below

```
return HttpResponse(config_data)
```

and for response you can check status

Comment: thanks, i can access the data but it will be in the text form. I actually want an object in my template so that i can iterate over it to get the required values.

Comment: user3327831 you must send a JSON, XML, or similar representation of the object.